# Creating paragraphs with automatic width

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs

I've got a bunch of paragraphs that I'm manually "tabbing out" using `hspace` of varying degree. After the varying amount of `hspace`, I'm trying to make a paragraph that fills the remaining width available on the page. Unfortunately, `parbox` requires a finite width to be passed to it, which isn't known unless I calculate it manually for each paragraph. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hspace{2in}
\parbox{\linewidth}{I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

**UPDATE**

I'm getting very close, but when I try to add my manually-numbered paragraphs, the right margin gets messed up again.

Here's an example. If I try to use `adjustwidth` again, it creates a line break after the section number which I don't want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5cm}{}
\parbox{\linewidth}{This paragraph runs to the proper end of the page. It will have a fair bit of space at the end, unlike the next paragraph which will overshoot it because of the makebox that's put in front of it.}
\makebox[2em]{1.1}\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image: Second result]

Comment: Hard to say given so little information but `tabularx` or (usually better) a list environment probably does what you need. Please _always_ include a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: I'll create a little sample to show the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added an example with an included image.

Comment: `\makebox[2em]{1.1}\parbox[t]{\linewidth}` is clearly 2em too wide but again you should be using a list environment with `\item[1.1]` not parboxes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Switching to `item` from `parbox` does give me something that's much closer to what I'm looking for. I think it's safe to say that last bit solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you would want to consider using the `changepage` package. With it you can locally adjust the margins of text in a page with the use of the environment, `adjustwidth`.

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{<leftmargin>}{<rightmargin>}
<content>
\end{adjustwidth}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{2.5cm}{} % Here 2.5cm defines the extra tabbing you need. The right margin is left untouched to keep the default right margin.
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

For the second question, you can use a list as David Carlisle suggested. This can be achieved as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5cm}{}
This paragraph runs to the proper end of the page. It will have a fair bit of space at the end, unlike the next paragraph which will overshoot it because of the makebox that's put in front of it.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=1.\arabic*,leftmargin=*]
    \item I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now playing with lists to make more robust:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{parin}{enumerate}{2} % depth of 2 can be changed depending on the necessity
\setlist[parin,1]{label*=1.\arabic*.,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[parin,2]{label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5cm}{}
This paragraph runs to the proper end of the page. It will have a fair bit of space at the end, unlike the next paragraph which will overshoot it because of the makebox that's put in front of it.
    \begin{parin}
    \item I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.
            \begin{parin}
                \item I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.
                \item I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.
            \end{parin}
        \item I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.
            \begin{parin}
                \item I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.
                \item I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.
            \end{parin}
    \end{parin}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer because it seems a bit simpler in my mind... I also don't feel like I'm really producing a "list" (unless my entire document is considered a list), so this seems more appropriate.

Comment: Hmm... this is so close! My problem now is that I have another space in the paragraph allocated to a section number. When I try to add that via a makebox, the text now shoots off the end of the page again. I'll add it as an update.

Comment: It's not quite solved yet! I've put an update in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The way to control margins in LaTeX is to use a list environment (compare the definition of `quote` in `article` class).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{list}{}{\setlength\leftmargin{2in}}\item\relax
I have a whole bunch of text here and it will extend past the edge of the page even though I'd like it to break before the page ends and act like a normal paragraph.
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like it will likely work once I translate it back to my document. How could I have figured this out on my own? I've been finding myself back at places like http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures a lot, but they don't even seem to mention `begin{list}`. I'd like to understand the syntax a bit better so I know what the empty curly braces are for, etc.

Comment: The latexbook or latex companion are the official references (not free of course) or this site or there are lots of packages using the same technique eg the `adustwidth` environment in the other answer is a wrapper making a list environment with perhaps a more natural syntax for this kind of case which isn't obviously a list. Or you could look at article.cls where the quote environment is defined exactly this way, but changes left and right margin, not just left.

Comment: Is "The latexbook" "Guide to LaTeX" by Kopka?

Comment: @aardvarkk no, the official latex manual is http://www.amazon.com/LaTeX-Document-Preparation-System-Edition/dp/0201529831/

Comment: Oh, and let me know if you have any ideas about the latest "gotcha"! I guess I simplified my document a bit more than I should have to provide an example...

Comment: @aardvarkk sorry I can't guess what is the intention of the nested parboxes in your revised question. given your original requirement to allow page breaking you clearly don't want any parbox to be involved, as  the main function of the box there  is to prevent page breaking.

Comment: They're not actually nested, right? One just has a numbered box in front of it which makes it appear nested, but they're not contained one-within-another. I'm just trying to find a solution so that I can have manually numbered paragraphs with varying left margins that don't exceed the right margin. Does that make sense? My updated example is just illustrating that once the content contained within the `adjustwidth` block includes a box (and not just a blob of text), it no longer deals properly with the right margin of the document.

Comment: I meant nested inside the adjustwidth, either way you do not want any `\parbox`.  List environments are designed for exactly this use. the adjustbox is irrelevant to your problem, surely it is clear that `\makebox[2em]{1.1}\parbox[t]{\linewidth}` is 2em wider than `\linewidth` so is 2em too large.

Comment: I'm fairly new to LaTeX (as is likely obvious from my approach). Academically, I can certainly understand why adding a 2em margin screws it up and makes it exactly 2em too large. My hope would be, however, that linewidth would be a variable that gets adjusted once I've changed the margins -- then `\linewidth` would always be the perfect size. That's basically what I was trying to achieve, but it seems I'm thinking about it in the wrong way.

Comment: @aardvarkk if you use a list environment the `\linewidth` is update to the new width taking indentation into account but it doesn't just change itself automatically, but parboxes are not what you want anyway as they prevent breaking

Comment: Any idea why the item label gets indented into the paragraph as it gets longer? For instance, using `\item[1.1]` works as expected, but `\item[1.1.1.1.1]` forces the last bit of the label into the paragraph of text to follow.

Comment: because the item label is wider than the indent in that case. See the enumitem package.